# Warning sign at WhatsApp backup in Google Drive

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-drive

I have an Android phone with WhatsApp installed that backs up to my Google Drive. When I go to the app settings in Google Drive, I see a warning next to WhatsApp (a gray triangle with an exclamation mark).

Why is that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/13047034/why-there-is-a-grey-triangle-with-exclamation-mark-next-to-my-whatsapp?hl=en#:%7E:text=Hi%2C,WhatsApp%20Support%20Team) from Google Support related to the same problem, it is a permission issue. Follow the steps as described on the message addressed to the OP of the mentioned thread by WhatsApp Support:

> Thanks for your message.
>
> There is an issue with the permission settings of your Google Drive account. You will need to access your Google Drive account to resolve this issue.
>
> On your PC, open Google Drive, click the gear icon in the top right > Settings > Manage Apps > WhatsApp > Options > make sure you haven't selected Disconnect from Google.
>
> To ensure WhatsApp functions properly on your device, please reset WhatsApp's app permissions.
>
> You can use your phone's search feature to search for your permissions settings, or follow these paths:
>
> - Android: Open your phone's Settings > Apps > WhatsApp > Permissions.
> - Android for Pixel: Open your phone's Settings > Apps & notifications > WhatsApp > Permissions.
>
> Be aware that the above paths may vary from phone to phone. Please contact your phone's manufacturer for specific instructions. You can restore or backup your chat history from Google Drive after you have given permission to WhatsApp and Google Drive. Please let us know If you continue to have issues.
>
> WhatsApp Support Team

From the same thread:

> Remove permissions of Whatsapp then do backup, Whatsapp will ask for permissions, you give it, and it should work. Found this on reddit.
>
> Link: https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsapp/comments/de5w9b/google_drive_backup_gray_triangle_with/

Comment: I found that text too. But when I go to google drive, the only option there is is to disconnect from Google. I haven't selected it though.

I can go to the permissions page on my phone, but there is no option to clear all permissions. I can only clear individual options, but there is no option that is even remotely related to backup to google drive. So I didn't know what to do with that explanation.

Comment: I have EXACTLY the same problem, followed exactly these same steps (found elsewhere initially) and haven't been able to solve this problem.